# Put a price value from an iframe inside a Magento product and then into the cart

Tags: php, jquery, magento

Inside an html page I wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function Prezzo( arg1 )
{
  var prezzoclasse = parent.document.getElementById("product-price-28");
  prezzoclasse.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerHTML = arg1; 
}
</script>
```

This html page is opened as an iframe inside a parent page ( http://test.arredodesignonline.com/it/materasso-francese-dresden.html ) , on which I pass the price value.

For now, it passes the price but without the currency, and once I add the product to the cart the price becomes 0.

How can I correctly pass the price value so it goes inside cart? We are using Magento 1.9.1

Thanks

Comment: could you please provides more details code ?

Comment: add some code it will help to understand

Comment: here's the parent page to see the source code http://test.arredodesignonline.com/it/materasso-francese-dresden.html (scegli il colore/choose the color will open the iframe)